# Trying to use tailwind bg image arbitrary value does not work

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Im struggling to show an image on the background using tailwind's https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values

however using the exact same url in a normal img tag displays the image

here is the div im trying to use the tailwind utility on:

```
            <div className="bg-[url('../../assets/header.jpeg')] bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center bg-fixed"></div>
```

here is the image tag:

```
const image = require('../../assets/header.jpeg')
<img className="object-cover w-full h-48" src={image} alt="Flower and sky" />
```

I understand im using require() for the image tag, but it rather shows that the path is correct.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML `div` look like?

Comment: its empty, in dev tools theres nothing under styles

Comment: What is the class name?

Comment: It shows the same values as I put into the div, however on the stylesheet section its has no styles

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `tailwind.config.js` file. You can define the path of the file like this in the file.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'myImg': "url('/assets/header.jpeg')",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```
<div className="bg-myImg bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center bg-fixed"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this as well

Comment: Then try to check the image path